# After adding .desktop file, the menu option does not start the application

Tags: lubuntu, menu

I'm using Lubuntu, and have added the text file myapp.desktop to /usr/share/applications.

I want the file to start an application, but instead it only launches the LXTerminal.

Here is the myapp.desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Sage
Comment=Sage Math
Categories=Development
Exec=/home/tim/Downloads/sage-6.2-x86_64-Linux/sage
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Name[en_US]=Sage Math
GenericName[en_US]=Sage Math
Comment[en_US]=Open Source Math Software
```

By the way, if I type the application path into LXTerminal, then the application does start correctly. Perhaps I'm missing something from the file I wrote?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, gksudo needed to be added to the .desktop file as there was an issue with Java, other than that here is the final .desktop file that launches matlab in Lubuntu.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=/usr/share/icons/matlab.png
Name=MATLAB
Comment=Start MATLAB - The Language of Technical Computing
#Uncomment the following line and comment the line after to
#force matlab to use the 32 bits architecture
#Exec=gksu -u root "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a_Student/bin/matlab -arch=glnx86 -desktop"
Exec=gksu -u root "/usr/local/MATLAB/R2013a_Student/bin/matlab -desktop"
Categories=Development;
#Uncomment the following line if you've got several matlab icons in the launcher
#StartupWMClass=com-mathworks-util-PostVMInit
```